# PHP open iframe on hover lost session

Tags: php, session, iframe

I'm trying to build an interactive monitoring tool for linux servers, i have an issue with sessions when hover a popup open but the session is lost, if i click on link instead of just hover the session is working when open in new tab.

> This is part of hover code

```
// Authenticate 
    //ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once 'db.php';

    // Check if connected else redirect to login.
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) ) 
    {
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit;
    }

 $xcrud->column_pattern('filesystem', '<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
        <li class="dropdown"> 
            <a href="http://monitor.fandc.ro/getvgsize.php?server_name=' . $server_name . '&filesystem={filesystem}">{value}</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <iframe frameBorder="0" src="http://svnserver.fandc.ro/getvgsize.php?server_name=' . $server_name . '&filesystem={filesystem}">{value}</iframe>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>');
```

> This is the page i added in iframe

```
// Authenticate 
    //ob_start();
    session_start();
    require_once 'db.php';

    // Check if connected else redirect to login.
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) ) 
    {
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit;
    }

    // getting service name in order to action on the selected service
$server_name = $_GET['server_name'];
$filesystem = $_GET['filesystem'];
echo "Filesystem: ";
echo $filesystem; 

// show vg size of each filesystem. 
$query3 = "select vg_$server_name.vgsize from df_$server_name, vg_$server_name where '%$filesystem%' LIKE CONCAT('%', vg_$server_name.vgname, '%')"; 
$xcrud7->query($query3);
$vg_size = $xcrud7->row(); 
$vgt = $vg_size['vgsize'];
if($vgt==null)
{
    $vgt = "No LVM";
}
echo "<br>FreeVG: ";
```

> Screenshots

[This is how it looks when hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nzjzo.png)

[If click on link session works ok.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cWLrz.png)